# couldn't find individual columns like 'year', 'quarter', 'semester', 'month' etc., in DimDate in data-model view of power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi

ello There,

I am trying to do some hands-on learning work to create data models in power bi; I imported 'DimDate', 'DimProduct', 'DimProductCategory', 'DimProductSubCategory', 'FactInternetSales' tables. With an objective to create hierarchy in DimDate table with columns 'Year', 'Quarter', 'Month' and etc, I tried to navigate to fields under DimDate table in 'Model' view of Power BI Desktop.

I couldn't find individual columns as I am expecting, rather there are aggregated columns of 'year', 'Quarter', 'Semester' and etc; my concern is why there are no non-aggregated columns relevant to 'year', 'quarter', 'semester, and etc. I did similar kind of modelling operations in SSAS-Tabular mode and now trying to accomplish similar and extended data modelling operations in Power BI desktop.

would anyone please me understand the scenario? Thank you for giving your valuable time. Please find the screenshot attached to this post.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this column is numeric then powerBI assumes that it is a summarized / aggregated value. Click on each column and change aggregation.

[image]

Comment: this information is helpful; thank you for your suppport!